# Changes in local file lost due to it synching with out of date remote git repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, git-push, git-revert

I tried to push a commit to my gitlab repo through the following commands (I'll describe output as I go):
`git checkout origin`  no branch called origin
`git checkout -b origin`
`git status`
`git add README.md`
`git add src/example.ipynb`
`git add src/.ipynb_checkpoints/`
`git commit -m notebook update`
`git push origin master`  this is where I realized I was probably on detached head and switched to master
`git checkout master`
`git status` still not showing changes
`git log -1`
`git checkout master`
`git reset --hard 44263cc6fd2bd60be54da344a6d344eb3c42a03a`
`git push origin master`

When I noticed my local notebook file reverted back to an old version I tried to revert that last published commit by doing
`git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --all`
`git revert 407302e`

Then I got the following error from running git revert:

`error: your local changes would be overwritten by revert.`
`hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.`
`fatal: revert failed`

So as you can see a series of bad decisions got me here, how do I recover the changes in my file? Thanks

Comment: As a sidenote, although you technically *can* name a branch `origin`, I'm afraid it's only leading to potential mistakes and confusions, given the extremely common usage within git world to use this name for the source remote of a repo. If not for you who created the repo, chances are someone will at some future point, and such whimsical naming could push them into a deadly "assumption trap".

Comment: The changes you want to recover are probably still in the branch you created called `origin`. Try `git show origin`, it should show the changes you made. If so, `git checkout origin` will bring you back to where you can see your changes. Then I suggest you give up on this sandbox and copy the changed files to a fresh new sandbox where you can commit them to `master`, which is probably where you wanted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it partly thanks to [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). Even though it was still impossible to revert the commit to due a merge conflict, it still allowed me to view the differences between the new and the old file which I pretty sure is achievable through commands as well but is a lot of work for a git noob like me.